# Custom Button doesn't apply static resource correctly

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have resources defined in the app.xaml as below

```
        <ResourceDictionary   x:Name="myResDic" >

            <!-- Styles -->
        <Color x:Key="grayDark">#959595</Color>
        <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#4fddb7" />
            <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="4" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource grayDark}" />
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="40" Android="50" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="wizardButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#3FFF" />
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#AFFF" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#4fddb7" />
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value=".5" />
        </Style>
```

if I bind it to a button like that in xamarin forms contentpage, it works fine

```
    <Button Text="Login with Facebook" Image="facebook.png"  
  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"  Style="{StaticResource wizardButton}"/>
```

But I create a custom button using ButtonRenderers in Android with the code below. But using like that style is not working correctly. Borders are not appearing. See the screenshot below. It is inheriting Button, why doesnt it work?

```
      <controls:FacebookLoginButton Text="Login with Facebook" Image="facebook.png" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"  Style="{StaticResource wizardButton}"/>

   <Button Text="Skip"    Style="{StaticResource wizardButton}"/>


        public class FacebookLoginButton : Button
        {
            public FacebookLoginButton()
            {

            }
        }
```

Obviously buttonrenderer is causing this problem. when I exclude it, it works fine. here is how my android buttonrenderer class looks like

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content; 
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Object = Java.Lang.Object;
using View = Android.Views.View;
using Xamarin.Facebook;
using myApp.Helpers.Controls;
using myApp.Droid;
using Android.Widget;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(FacebookLoginButton), typeof(FacebookLoginButtonRendererAndroid))]
namespace myApp.Droid
{
    public class FacebookLoginButtonRendererAndroid : ButtonRenderer
    {
        private static Activity _activity;
        public FacebookLoginButtonRendererAndroid(Context context)
                  : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            _activity = this.Context as Activity;

            //DEBUG
            //Xamarin.Facebook.Login.LoginManager.Instance.LogOut();

            if (this.Control != null)
            {
                Button button = this.Control;
                button.SetOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener.Instance.Value);
            }

            if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken != null)
            {
                App.PostSuccessFacebookAction(AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.Token);
            }
        }

        private class ButtonClickListener : Object, IOnClickListener
        {
            public static readonly Lazy<ButtonClickListener> Instance = new Lazy<ButtonClickListener>(() => new ButtonClickListener());

            public void OnClick(View v)
            {
                var myIntent = new Intent(_activity, typeof(FacebookActivity));
                _activity.StartActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

The first is to remove the key from the style so it applies to all buttons of type FacebookLoginButton.

This is an implicit style and [details can be found here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/implicit/)

```
<Style TargetType="FacebookLoginButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#3FFF" />
    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#AFFF" />
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#4fddb7" />
    <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value=".5" />
 </Style>
```

The second way is to add a bindable style property to the facebook button user control, bind it to a style in XAML and implement it in the custom renderer.

Comment: So you mean that it doesnt work with inheritance. even if I inherit from Button, new type is the custom type, I cant use the inherited type as TargetType of the Style?

Comment: Yes it works by inheritance, but I was showing a way of using an implicit style to force the style to be used. Added documentation link to answer around this.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the style binding in your code as it was way off to the right

Comment: Just checked and my inherited button successfully showed the style from a base control. I'm guessing something in your renderer is preventing the style from being applied.

Comment: you are right. it was the renderer class in android project was causing this problem. when I excluded it, it works fine. please see my updated question.

Comment: The constructor looks strange. Renderer constructors don't usually have parameters.

Comment: this is new with xamarin's latest release which came out a week ago. earlier versions didnt have it this way.

Comment: it looks like that this was a bug in Xamarin forms. I have just updated latest version and without any code change or fix, problem is resolved :)